# Django installation - Syntax error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

After running below steps,

```
# cd /usr/lib/python
  python2.7/ python3/   python3.5/ python3.6/
# easy_install3 --version
  setuptools 20.7.0 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (Python 3.5)
# whoami
  root
# echo $PYTHONPATH
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
# 
# easy_install3 --install-dir /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages django==1.9
  Creating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/site.py
 Searching for django==1.9
 Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
 Best match: Django 1.9
 Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/c2/14/e282ae720c21b48316b66126d7295ace0790438b27482b7a3dd9a6e3c3e1/Django- 1.9.tar.gz#md5=110389cf89196334182295165852e082
 Processing Django-1.9.tar.gz
 Writing /tmp/easy_install-5672_wl4/Django-1.9/setup.cfg
 Running Django-1.9/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-5672_wl4/Django-1.9/egg-dist-tmp-iuog46mc
 no previously-included directories found matching 'django/contrib/admin/bin'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
     class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 creating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.9-py3.5.egg
 Extracting Django-1.9-py3.5.egg to /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.9-py3.5.egg/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.9-py3.5.egg/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 Adding Django 1.9 to easy-install.pth file
 Installing django-admin.py script to /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
 Installing django-admin script to /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages

 Installed /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.9-py3.5.egg
 Processing dependencies for django==1.9
 Finished processing dependencies for django==1.9
#
```

---

I see syntax error in Django code, amidst installation.

**Edit:**

After fixing easy_install issue, I see the same error,

```
$ sudo easy_install django==1.9
Searching for django==1.9
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/c2/14/e282ae720c21b48316b66126d7295ace0790438b27482b7a3dd9a6e3c3e1/Django-1.9.tar.gz#md5=110389cf89196334182295165852e082
Best match: Django 1.9
Processing Django-1.9.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-oayz20ph/Django-1.9/setup.cfg
Running Django-1.9/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-oayz20ph/Django-1.9/egg-dist-tmp-nrnqftyo
no previously-included directories found matching 'django/contrib/admin/bin'
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

creating /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Django-1.9-py3.6.egg
Extracting Django-1.9-py3.6.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Django-1.9-py3.6.egg/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Django-1.9-py3.6.egg/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Adding Django 1.9 to easy-install.pth file
Installing django-admin.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing django-admin script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Django-1.9-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for django==1.9
Finished processing dependencies for django==1.9
$
```

---

Currently used pip3 approach and installed django

---

**Question:**

Can this syntax error get ignored?

Comment: How about running the Django tests and check if everything works fine.

Comment: Hmm... `Django-1.9-py3.5.egg` in `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` which looks weird. Looks like wrong `easy_install` tool

Comment: Just curious that why you are not using pip?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki No idea, it is about having right pip or easy_install tool, I guess. Can you help me provide links for downloading easy_install & pip? to install with python3.6

Comment: Which platform are you on ? Fedora ? Ubuntu?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Working on Ubuntu 16.x OS. [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.6#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x) give 404 error. wrong URI

Answer (score 0):

Use apt-get to install pip on Ubuntu

For python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then installation of django won't be no problem

For installation of django in python3

```
pip3 install django
```

If you have py3.6 already then

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Then to install Django with py3.6

```
python3.6 -m pip install django
```

Comment: See the edit. Also specify the version with `django==1.9`

Comment: Problem is `pip3 --version` points to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` but not `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`

Comment: Then change the default python

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Since your pip points to a different python version you need to either create an alias or change the default python version from py3 to py3.6